# Отображение картинок после размещения на хостинге в Django

Tags: django, heroku, img

Разместил проект на хостинге Heroku проект на Django. Не отображаются картинки.
Хранились в папке media на уровне проекта.
С такими настройками:

в settings:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

в urls:

urlpatterns = [

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

path("__debug__/", include("debug_toolbar.urls")),

path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),

path('', include('shop.urls')),
```

]

if settings.DEBUG:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

На локальном все работало.
Попробовал через админку выбрать картинки еще раз, чтобы прописался путь, не помогло.
В какой папке их правильно хранить и какие ссылки прописывать?